# iOS FaceID/TouchID issue with multiple users enrolling in the same setup session

Tags: ios, face-id, localauthentication

When trying to enroll for FaceID there are two steps to scan the user's face. On the first step person A enrolls his face and on the second scan person B enrolls his face. Both enrollments are accepted and authentication works only for person A who enrolled first.

**Steps to Reproduce:**

Go to FaceID settings and enroll for Face ID..

Complete the first scan with person A.

Complete the second scan with person B.

**Expected Results:**

Second scan with person B should fail.

**Actual Results:**

Second scan with person B succeeds.
Authentication works only for person A and not person B

**Version/Build:**

iOS 12.0

**Configuration:**

iPhone X

Any idea why iOS is allowing setup FaceID with multiple users in a single scan? I am aware of alternate appearance which can be used by two people but I am trying to do this without alternate appearance.

**The Touch ID piece:**

When trying to enroll for TouchID users need to scan their fingerprint multiple times and during this process if two users give their fingerprints alternatively then both the users can authenticate successfully.

**Steps to Reproduce:**

Go to Touch ID settings and enroll for Touch ID.

Tap on the sensor alternatively as person A & person B. 
Authenticate with persona A & Authenticate with person B

**Expected Results:**

Only one person should have access.

**Actual Results:**

Both person A and person B have access.
Authentication works only for person A and not person B

**Version/Build:**

iOS 12.0

**Configuration:**

iPad Pro

Any idea why iOS is allowing setup FaceID with multiple users in a single scan? I am aware of alternate appearance which can be used by two people but I am trying to do this without alternate appearance.